# Expected an indented block error

Tags: error, indentation

Followings is my code. I use it in QGIS 3.8.2.
It shows "Expected an indented block" error.
Please help me to sort the error out.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.name() == "Tree": 
with edit(layer):
        layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Name", QVariant.String, ",", 255) ] )
        layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Height", QVariant.String, ",", 255) ] )

else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python uses indentation to denote blocks of code, for example inside loops or `if` conditions, and also `with`. Basically whenever there's a `:` at the end of a line. So this should work:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.name() == "Tree": 
      with edit(layer):
        layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Name", QVariant.String, ",", 255) ] )
        layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Height", QVariant.String, ",", 255) ] )

    else:
      pass
```

Although you should probably indent it consistently, with maybe four spaces per block.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. :)
Now i am facing the following error. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'QgsMapLayerRegistry' is not defined

Comment: New error, new question please. Try and fix it yourself first though.